# Select item in a gridview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm trying to create a webpage where a user can click on an item inside a gridview and have that rows data display in another page. I cannot figure out how to set it up so only the selected row's information is displayed in (I am thinking I will use a form view to display the data on the second page) the form view on the second page. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Jake

Comment: your question is unclear? be a bit more specific.

Comment: I have a gridview.. when I click on the select button in a row, I want it to go to another page and display the selected rows information on the page.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have just a couple of columns i did suggest you to use `QueryString` to pass values between pages. Lets say there are two such values you want to pass to another page:

```
Response.Redirect("default2.aspx?firstvalue=" + yourfirstvalue + "&secondvalue=" + yoursecondvalue"); 
// this will set the values you want to pass on your gridview page

Request.QueryString("firstvalue") 
// this will retrieve the first value from URL from your second page
```

> If you want a neat lookin URL then i would suggest you to use `Session` variables.

Comment: Mark it as useful/answered if it helped you.

Comment: I would agree with the session variables. Grab them in your databind event and then pass whem to the next page.